# Livewire: tinymce.activeEditor.setContent doesn't change variable

Tags: tinymce, laravel-livewire

When I ran the command `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('text')` in the console. It changed the input field, but the livewire variable just won't change.

Comment: And what does the rest of the code look like? The html and script

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bUXE38mT

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question